# How to names lists under list when using lapply?

Tags: r, nested-lists, lapply, names

I have a two nested loop which I want to do it with lapply instead of for loops. I have made up the following simple example:

```
a<-as.list(c(1,2))  
b<-as.list(c(6,7))  
results<-lapply(a, function(x) lapply(b, function(y) x+y))

> results  
[[1]]  
[[1]][[1]]  
[1] 7  

[[1]][[2]]  
[1] 8  


[[2]]  
[[2]][[1]]  
[1] 8

[[2]][[2]]  
[1] 9
```

how can I assign names to this list, I can assign names to the first level using names(result)<-a, but I do not know how to do it for the second level. And naming should be done in loop since in my main program length of b may change.
I appreciate if any one can give me some hint.

Answer (score 6):

You should note that `lapply()` itself is just a wrapper for a well constructed `for()` loop, so you're not gaining any efficiency, just perhaps readability.  That aside, the easiest approach is to add names to the lists going into your nested `lapply()` calls:

```
a<-as.list(c(1,2))
b<-as.list(c(6,7)) 
names(a) <- c("a","b")
names(b) <- c("c", "d")
results<-lapply(a, function(x) lapply(b, function(y) x+y))
```

This approach yields:

```
> results
$a
$a$c
[1] 7

$a$d
[1] 8


$b
$b$c
[1] 8

$b$d
[1] 9
```

You can of course then rename nested components like this:

```
> names(results$a) <- c("e","f")
> results$a
$e
[1] 7

$f
[1] 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I want to put the  names(b)<-c("c","d")  in the lapply. How can I do that? I am not sure how I should include this in the lapply

Comment: Can you explain why, or improve your supplied example above as to what you really want to see as a result?

Comment: @newbie maybe you should consider naming `b` when it is created, otherwise it's hard to see what you'd like to improve without a better working example