# naming list of lists and list of lists of lists in r

Tags: r

I have a list such as:

```
myList <- list(a1 = list(list("a11", "a12")), a2 = list(list("a21", "a22")))
```

Which looks like:

```
$a1
$a1[[1]]
$a1[[1]][[1]]
[1] "12345"

$a1[[1]][[2]]
[1] "678910"



$a2
$a2[[1]]
$a2[[1]][[1]]
[1] "98765"

$a2[[1]][[2]]
[1] "43210"
```

I can rename the lists using `names(myList) <- c("a1new", "a2new")`. However how can I rename the different levels of the list? Such that I want to rename `[[1]]` of `a1` and `[[1]]` of `a2` and also the lists `$a2new[[1]][[1]]` and `$a2new[[1]][[2]]`.

Comment: Have u tred something along these lines: names(myList$a1) <- "new"
Additionlly you can access particular list elements with the `[` function eg within `sapply` example: `sapply(myList, \`[`, 2)`

Comment: the 5 Minute edit rule broke my code example here again uncluding the missing final \`... example: `sapply(myList, \`[\`, 2)`

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the `[` function. I would like to rename them based on some vector and avoid writing out multiple times `names(mylist$a1) <- "newa1"`

Comment: If `myList` is the input then what is the output?

Comment: the input would be something like `mynames <- c("newa1", "newa2")` then I would like to name the second level of the list as these new names.

Comment: maybe look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349331/how-to-names-lists-under-list-when-using-lapply

Comment: and since apply family of functions are basically for loops and you we are not talking about massive loop sizes here - just hack it with a for loop

Comment: I think I will just go with something more simple and try to rename all level 2 lists as "newlistname". How can I do this using your `sapply` example? `sapply(names(myList), `[`, 2) <- "newlistname"`

Comment: I can do something like `names(myList[[1]]) <- "newname"` which will change the name of the first list. How can I `lapply` or `sapply` to change all of the lists (to the same name)?

Comment: `map(myList, ~map(.x, ~setNames(c("newnames"))))` does not work but I think I am getting closer with `map(myList, ~map(.x, ~names(.), "newname"))`